# PowerShell Get-AzureWebSiteJob error: "git not found"

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm in Azure PowerShell 0.8.15.1, in AzureServiceManagement mode, trying to run Get-AzureWebJob. If I type the command with no parameters, expecting to be prompted for the -Name and/or -JobName, I get instead:

"Git not found. Please install git and place it in your command line path."

I am not using git. Why this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/Services/Commands.Utilities/Websites/Common/WebsiteContextBaseCmdlet.cs), it looks like the cmdlet is trying to infer the website name using the Azure website git integration. Apparently they assume everybody will have git installed.

Comment: This is nuts. They check if you have a Name, but don't check if you have a GitWebsite! There should be a separate parameter to allow the developer, not Microsoft, to dictate whether a GitWebsite is involved.

Comment: To expand this answer: the solution is to include the website name as parameter.

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/273